# unsure of what design to use for this specific case

Tags: c++

For example, I have a clan and a character. There's a character that is the leader. To give the clan a specific feature, some money from the character is required.

I don't want to have too much tight coupling. Right now I have a member in the `clan` class like this:

```
bool clan::give_rank(character* chr, int rank)
{ 
    if (!is_leader(chr.id()) || !chr->has_money(500))
       return false;

    this->rank_ = rank;
    chr->take_money(500); 
    return true;
}
```

Is this tight coupling? or maybe I should have a secondary class like a clan_mgr that connects both classes?

```
bool clan_mngr::give_rank(character* chr, int rank)
{ 
    clan* myclan = chr->get_clan(); 

    if (!myclan || !myclan->is_leader(chr.id()) || !chr->has_money(500))
       return false;

    myclan->rank_ = rank;
    chr->take_money(500);
    return true;
}
```

// Or maybe this one, which looks even worse imo:

```
bool character::give_rank_to_clan(int rank)
{ 
    clan* myclan = chr->get_clan(); 

    if (!myclan || !myclan->is_leader(id()) || !has_money(500))
       return false;

    myclan->rank_ = rank;
    TakeMoney(500);    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling is a bit of an art, but you're trying to reduce and formalise the API usage between classes.  Consider:

```
bool clan_characters::give_rank_to_clan(character& c, int rank)
{
    auto clan = c.get_clan();
    if (clan)
        if (c.try_pay(500))
           if (clan->try_set_rank_by_id(rank, c.id())
               return true;
           else
               c.try_pay(-500); // always works for -ve amount ;-)
    return false;
}
```

With the above:

- logic affecting both `clan`s and `character`s is separated into a `clan_characters` namespace or `struct`/`class` (if you find a need for data), rather than "`clan_mngr`" which to me sounds like a resource management object for one or more clans
- you don't need to fix anything if the type returned by `get_clan()` changes to anything with pointer semantics that allows access to a `try_set_rank_by_id` function
- the `character` class is providing a `try_pay()` function supporting the higher level logical operation, so later on you could do something like make it atomic and call it from multiple threads without any changes to calling code (e.g. you won't have two threads call `has_money(500)`, both see only 500, then both spend it)
- the `clan` has a `try_set_rank_by_id` function that can internally manage the logic check whether a character id is allowed to set the rank, and what member variable or data structure gets updated.  For example, if a deputy leader was introduced that could set the rank, only the internals of `try_set_rank_id` would need to be updated and not the client code.

Further options:

- you could pass the `clan` is as a function argument, either:

  - `template <typename Clan> bool give_rank_to_clan(Clan* my_clan, ...)`, which grants greatest "duck typing" freedom to supply arbitrary mock clan types during testing, or
  - `bool give_rank_to_clan(decltype(character::get_clan()) my_clan, ...)` or just `clan* my_clan`, which still let you pass `clan`-derived types; most useful for testing if `clan::try_set_rank_by_id()` is made `virtual`
- you could have `try_set_rank_by_character(rank, c)` - meaning the function doesn't have to be changed if `try_set_rank_by_character` wants to use some other aspect of the character data instead of the `id`, but that does couple `clan` more tightly to `character`: short term it at least needs to know to call `id()` - there is no perfect choice.